# c++ class member initialization (poco)

Tags: c++, oop, class, initialization, poco-libraries

i am making a wrapper for my use for database, using Poco::Database::ODBC

the normal code is supposed to be like :

```
Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
Session ses("ODBC", "DSN=mytest;Uid=mytest;Pwd=mytest");
bool bConnected = ses.isConnected();
Statement select(ses);
select << "SELECT firstname FROM Patients", range(0, 10);
RecordSet rs(select);
while (!select.done())
{
    select.execute();
    bool more = rs.moveFirst();
    while (more)
    {
        for (std::size_t col = 0; col < rs.columnCount(); ++col)
        {
            std::cout << rs[col].convert<std::string>() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        more = rs.moveNext();
    }
}

Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::unregisterConnector();
```

This works just fine.

Now for my class

```
class database{
     Session ses; //Since this is needed all for all the queries.
   public:
     database():ses("ODBC", "DSN=name;uid=user;pwd=pass"){
     }
};//end class
```

how do i call `Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector()` before initialization call of `ses`

I tried

```
database():Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector(),ses("ODBC", "DSN=name;uid=user;pwd=pass"){
}
```

but this doesnt works. it gives error

`'registerConnector' : is not a member of 'Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector'`

how should i do it ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do it outside `database::database()`, or use a pointer to a `Session` instead of a member, and allocate it on the heap inside the constructor. Something like:

```
database::database()
{
    Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
    ses = new Session("ODBC", "DSN=name;uid=user;pwd=pass");
}

database::~database()
{
    delete ses;
}
```

Comment: `ses` is to be used in statements like `ses << "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer", into(count), now;` , i tried this approach earlier, but then these statements give error.

Comment: `(*ses) << "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer"` will work.
Or: `Session &sessRef = *ses;
sessRef << "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer` if you find it too clumsy.

Comment: One further note: since it seems that you could have many `database`, but you'd like to call `registerConnector` only once, I think the best way would be to do the call to `registerConnector` once and only once in `main()`, and then use your original code (member variable, with initialization list).

Answer (score 1):

To enable this kind of functionality directly, you write a RAII-style wrapper object around the `registerConnector` function:

```
class wrapper {
public:
    wrapper() {
        Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
    }
    ~wrapper() {
        Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::unregisterConnector();
    }
}
```

So you can now do:

```
class database{
     Wrapper wrap;
     Session ses; //Since this is needed all for all the queries.
   public:
     database() : wrap(), ses("ODBC", "DSN=name;uid=user;pwd=pass"){
     }
};
```

However, I don't think this is a good design; it leaves unanswered questions:

1. Why are you initializing the database *subsystem* in the `database` wrapper? Maybe it should be done as part of the program's init routine?
2. What happens if multiple `database` objects get used at the same time? Registering/unregistering would cause problems; doing the init as above would not.

Comment: i think you will want to declare Wrapper before Session so that it is instantiated/initialized first.  the constructor initialization list does not control that (at least not under gcc which will warn about this code).

Comment: `ses` will be initialized first. The order of evaluation in an initialization list is that in which the members are defined and not the order they are called in the initialization list. This is because a single order needs to be ensured among all constructors, so that the destructor can destruct things in the opposite order.

Comment: @Jon: OK i made this, but this doesn't seems to solve the problem, somehow wrap is not being called before ses (as Nathan above mentioned probably).

for your questions, i assume it is not good design, but i am not very experienced with the +/- of various designs. I am a student yet.

1. I suppose it should be with programs init routine, i was trying to keep the database part apart together.

2. Since i have a single database to query, i plan to keep only one object at a time, although i see your point for multiple databases.

Thanks

Comment: @K-ballo: You are of course totally right, thanks for the gotcha. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `registerConnector` is a free function. To call other functions within the initialization list, you can use the comma operator:

```
 database()
    : ses(
        ( Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector(), "ODBC" )
        , "DSN=name;uid=user;pwd=pass"
      )
 {...}
```

The builtin comma operator evaluates two expressions and returns the result of the second one.

Alternatively, you may be able to create a custom class that handles the `registerConnector()` class, and place it within the class before `ses` so that its construction will happen before that of `ses`.

Comment: compiler says `registerConnector` is undefined in this case.

Comment: @Pheonix: You should -of course- use the full name in real code so it should actually be `Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector()`

Comment: i did Tried that as well, Error says argument list doesn't matches.